# Decouple Spring JDBC Authentication with '/login' url

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-security, spring-jdbc, restful-authentication

I am working on Spring JDBC authentication. And i learnt it from below websites

http://javasampleapproach.com/spring-framework/spring-security/use-spring-security-jdbc-authentication-postgresql-spring-boot#comment-843

https://medium.com/@gustavo.ponce.ch/spring-boot-spring-mvc-spring-security-mysql-a5d8545d837d

Problem is that all these example has an endpoint that returns FE 'view' name and Front-end is built in.

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/login"})
    public String login(){
        return "login";
    }

@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll().antMatchers("/admin").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll().and().logout()
                .permitAll();
        http.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403");
    }
```

In my project, all FE code resides in 'web-entry' folder, developed in 'React-js' by FE guyz. and i don't understand how can i manage to call the 'React-js' login page like they do in 
*'authenticated().and()**.formLogin().loginPage("/login")**...'*

I want to do something like this,

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeRequests().//
            antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/customer/**").hasRole("USER").//
            antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/customer").hasRole("LEAD").//
            antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/customer/**").hasRole("LEAD").//
            antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/customer/**").hasRole("ADMIN").and().//
            csrf().disable();
}
```

Comment: You have to build the backend as a service. Secure it using something like JSON web token. When you authenticate a user you create a token that will be used to verify that the user is authenticated and authorized every time he requests protected routes.

Comment: Any links for tutorial or how can i do this with Spring-Security

Comment: Check this out [Secure a Spring Boot REST API With JSON Web Token + Reference to Angular Integration](https://medium.com/@nydiarra/secure-a-spring-boot-rest-api-with-json-web-token-reference-to-angular-integration-e57a25806c50)